# LibreOffice Calc - Disable rounding

Tags: libreoffice

There are a [ton of threads](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=libreoffice%20rounding%20numbers%20turn%20off&oq=libre&gs_l=hp.3.1.35i39l2j0j0i20j0l3j0i10j0l2.2244.3146.0.5748.6.6.0.0.0.0.170.632.4j2.6.0.stareytweb...0...1.1.64.hp..1.5.461.0.3JWkPwjQFxY) on this topic, but no simple and definitive answers.

Can someone please tell me how to permanently disable cell rounding on the .csv file which is created by script?

Basically, '**377635637222436751**' is being converted to '**377635637222437000**' automatically and that isn't really acceptable for my needs.

I've tried this:
*Tools->Options->Calc->Calculate "Precision as shown"*

and this:
*Format > Cells > Numbers > Category > (scroll down for) Text.*
(but considering my script creates the .csv -- this option isn't very good since it must be done after the file is created)

And neither is working.  The number stays rounded -- even after formatting the column after the file is created.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For what I know, LibreOffice has no arbitrary precision numbers (decimal or integers). So if the number [exceeds the range of a long integer](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Using_Variables) it is [stored as an IEEE754 number](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/8006/libreoffice-calc-calculation-error/) and so it has a limited precision.

So basically you can't do calculations with arbitrary precision in Calc, and if you want to read the long number as a number you will have it rounded off.

If you do not need to do calculations, use a string; put in your `csv`:

```
,
,
,12345678901234678901234567890
,"123456789012345678901234567890"
```

(notice the quotation marks) and then when reading it be sure to add "quoted field as text" and the correct text delimiter:

[image: importing csv]

...and you have

[image: result]

Now --- if you touch, transform, eval the string --- you will have the rounding kicking in again.

Maybe you can use currency type which is a 64 bit integer, but as far as I know there is no way to force that via `csv`.